# Proof about convex combinations of vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

For $x,y\in{R^n}$,a segment between x and y is defined as:

$[x,y]:={\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y : 0≤\lambda ≤1}$

If we complete the segment $[x,y]$ beyond its ends we get an affine line:

$l_{x,y}={\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y : \lambda \in R}$.

Prove that $z\in l_{x,y}$ iff $x\in[y,z]$ for $\lambda ≥1$ $\cup$ $y\in[x,z]$ for $\lambda ≥ 0$  $\cup$  $z\in [x,y]$ for $0 ≤\lambda ≤1$

I proved the => direction by assuming $z\in l_{x,y}$, writing $z={\lambda x +(1-\lambda )y} $ $\lambda\in{R}$ then finding $x$ and $y$ in terms of the other veriables and concluding which $\lambda$ is suitable for each one.
I tried hard to prove the other direction but I didn't manage to get it.